# Create a random number each second

Tags: after-effects

In After Effects I am trying my hands at this

and would like to add a random number between 45 and 55 in the upper right corner, which should change each second.

If I use Math.round(random(45,55)) I am getting pretty close, but the number updates maybe 20 times a second making it unusable. Is there a way to control how often a new number is generated? Is there another way to do this?

Just to clarify, I want sort of what is already in wiggle, where wiggle(1,30) wiggles once a second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`random` updates at the sub-frame level (so its value actually changes even during a frame, for example when motion blur is on. You can see this as you zoom in on the graph editor of a property with a random value, it keeps changing as it zooms and the time is sub-sampled more).

To force it to update only once a second you need to use the [`seedRandom`](http://adobe.ly/1DZW3md) function, with the `timeless` attribute set to `true`, and a `seed` that changes every second. Using `Math.floor(time)` will return a value that increases once every second, on the second.

So something like:

```
seedRandom(Math.floor(time), timeless = true);
random(45,55);
```

will create a random value that stays constant for 1 second, and

```
var holdTime = 5;
seedRandom(Math.floor(time/holdTime), timeless = true);
random(45,55);
```

will stay constant for 5 seconds - you can change the value of the variable `holdTime` to control how long the value holds for. For example to change once every frame, but not during sub-frame intervals set it to `holdTime = thisComp.frameDuration;`

Comment: If you want eg. 5 seconds, it's time/5